How to update a list of dicts keys' value in jinja2
I have set the dicts' keys domain to an empty string "". I am checking if the var field for dict key ssluser is defined, and if so, I then need to fill in the email domain key data extracted from that provided user value.
{% 
  set sslusers= [
    {      
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User01,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED01,
      'index': 0,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User02,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED02,
      'index': 1,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {     
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User03,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED03,
      'index': 2,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {   
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User04,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED04,
      'index': 3,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {      
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User05,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED05,
      'index': 4,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User06,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED06,
      'index': 5,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {     
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User07,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED07,
      'index': 6,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {   
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User08,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED08,
      'index': 7,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {      
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User09,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED09,
      'index': 8,
      'domain': ""
    },
    {
      'ssluser': SSL_VPN_User10,
      'sslusercred': SSL_USER_CRED10,
      'index': 9,
      'domain': ""
    }
  ] 
%}

The jinja block am I trying to get working to do this:
{%- for item in sslusers if item.ssluser is defined %}
    {% set domain_value_old = item.domain %}
    {% for key, value in item.items() %}
        {% if key == 'domain' %}
            {% set domain_value_new = item.domain.split('@') | last %}
            <update dicts in the list with the new value only for 'domain' key>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

I am stuck on the part after {% if key == 'domain' %}, for one I get domain_value_new is not defined, and then I do not know how to update the key to the new value after, if I can get it defined at all. For context, I am using this in a cli script that is a jinja template that runs on network appliances.
UPDATE ---
I was able to get past the undefined var part with this block:
{%- for item in sslusers if item.ssluser is defined %}
    {% set domain_value_old = item.domain %}
    {% set domain_value_new = item.ssluser.split('@') | last %}
    {% for dict_item in item['domain'] %}
        <do the thing here>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


Just do item['domain'] = domain_value_new?

Will try, but exactly in that syntax? Or do I use {% set item['domain'] = domain_value_new %}

I don't actually know Jinja, I just assumed it copies Python's syntax for assignments.

This is the working solution for my use-case
{%- for item in sslusers if item.ssluser is defined %}
    {% set domain_value_new = item.ssluser.split('@') | last %}
    {%- set _ = item.update({'domain': domain_value_new}) -%}
{% endfor %}

